# Ruby method that uppercases even indexed letters and lowercases odd

Tags: ruby, string

## Directions:

Write a method that accepts a string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word lower cased. The indexing just explained is zero based, so the zero-ith index is even, therefore that character should be upper cased.

The passed in string will only consist of alphabetical characters and spaces(' '). Spaces will only be present if there are multiple words. Words will be separated by a single space(' ').

## My code:

*(someone please refactor or explain to me a cleaner/shorter solution)*

```
def weirdcase(string)
  arr = string.split(' ')
  arr.map! {|word|
    char = word.chars
    char.each_with_index do |letter, i|
      i % 2 == 0 ? letter.upcase! : letter.downcase!
    end
  }
  arr.map! {|a| a.push(' ').join('')}
  x = arr.join('').to_s
  x[0...-1]
end
```

Comment: This seems more like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Mark, didn't know that there was a codereview stack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way you could do that, using [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to create an enumerator and [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to replace every character in the string with its value upcased or downcased.

```
def weirdcase(str)
  enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
  str.gsub(/./) do |s|
    if s == ' '
      enum.rewind
      s
    else
      s.public_send(enum.next)
    end
  end
end

weirdcase "Mary had a little lamb"
  #=> "MaRy hAd a lItTlE LaMb"
```

By making `gsub`'s argument `/./` each character in the string is replaced by the value returned by the block, which, if that character is not a space, is that character either upcased or downcased, depending on the symbol generated by the enumerator `enum`, which alternates between `:upcase` and `:downcase` for each word.

Note that

```
enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [:upcase, :downcase]:cycle>
enum.next
  #=> :upcase
enum.next
  #=> :downcase
enum.next
  #=> :upcase
```

and so on. See also [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

[Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind) is needed to begin anew the alternating of case with each word.

One could replace `s.public_send(enum.next)` with

```
enum.next == :upcase ? s.upcase : s.downcase
```

Comment: Good solution. One minor nitpick, though. This way a downcase/upcase's "turn" is "wasted" on a space.

Comment: Hardly a minor nitpick, @Sergio. I missed "in each word" in the statement of the problem. I assume the index of the first character in each word is zero, not the character's index in the string. (That assumption also makes the question more interesting.) I fixed my answer. The problem could be stated more clearly, however, but that is evidently what was given to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: ah, turns out my understanding of the problem was also flawed. But I'm glad it still helped you improve the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `gsub` to change two adjacent characters at a time:

```
def weirdcase(string)
  string.gsub(/(.)(.?)/) { "#{$1.upcase}#{$2.downcase}" }
end

weirdcase "Mary had a little lamb"
#=> "MaRy hAd a lItTlE LaMb"
```

The `?` makes the second character optional, which is needed for odd-length strings:

```
weirdcase "foo"
#=> "FoO"
```

Or a using [`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
def weirdcase(string)
  string.each_char.map.with_index { |char, index|
    if index.odd?
      char.downcase
    else
      char.upcase
    end
  }.join
end
```

If you want to change each word separately:

```
"Mary had a little lamb".split(' ').map { |word| weirdcase(word) }.join(' ')
#=> "MaRy HaD A LiTtLe LaMb"
```

or again with `gsub`:

```
"Mary had a little lamb".gsub(/\S+/) { |word| weirdcase(word) }
#=> "MaRy HaD A LiTtLe LaMb"
```

Comment: an alternative: each_slice.